# Patience is a virtue best served cold

Tags: meaning

My college professor asked our class for any creative insight about the phrase, “Patience is a virtue best served cold.”
My - and my other classmates’s - initial reaction was that our teacher may have meant, “Revenge is a dish best served cold.”
However, when we said this, our teacher simply stated it again.
Does anyone have creative thoughts on the saying?

Comment: It is, at first blush, irony/parody.  You can philosophize about it several ways, but that's philosophy/psychology, not English.

Comment: What is the question here? It seems to be an opinion poll.

Comment: Oddly enough, the expression does appear—exactly once—in Google Books search results. The source is a self -published novel by DJ Stoneham, [_Alice Falls Again_](https://books.google.com/books?id=cPN6DwAAQBAJ&pg=PT60&dq=%22Patience+is+a+virtue+best+served+cold%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwie_tOX8NTfAhVtCjQIHSzGD-AQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=%22Patience%20is%20a%20virtue%20best%20served%20cold%22&f=false) (2018): "She heard her mother's voice in her head: 'Patience is a virtue, best served cold' or something like that." So perhaps your professor moonlights as a fan fiction novelist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see it, patience in most cases *is* better when served with coldness. If you pretend to be patient, it's always better to act colder, more indifferent - even though you might be feeling angry, disappointed, etc. If you act cold, you're showing something is tiring you in a somewhat more polite way, but, most importantly, you're not exactly pushing non-existent emotions upon yourself. On the other hand, showing warm patience (and by that I mean really feeling it through and reassuring yourself you can and *must* bear with someone, even if they're harmful/rude/toxic) is going to end badly for both you and the other person.

Everything is good to a certain extent. As the saying goes: everything is a good thing, except for when it isn't.